# How to open the view and edit page inside the colorbox?

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs, javascript

I am using an full calendar with event as a node.
[image]
I have disabled the overlay module.

In the full calendar settings->colorbox options, I have enabled 'open events in a colorbox'

[image]

Now when I click on any events in the full calendar it opens the node view page in colorbox which has two tabs **view** and **edit** .

[image]

When I click on **edit** tab , it opens into a new page instead of loading inside the colorbox.
How can I achieve loading of **view** and **edit** tab **inside the colorbox** and prevent the redirect which occurs when clicked on edit page? .

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify more precise which html elements of the destination page (the page containing the event) should be rendered.

i guess changing the id selector to

#content .content

will do the job.